# How to create a realistic bevel effect on text in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, effects, layer-style

I found this image on google and was fascinated by the realism of the bevel effect and wanted to learn how to do it myself.

I tried some stuffs but they were not close enough. I want to replicate the exact same effect.
[image]

Here's what I tried:

[image]

```
Bevel & Emboss: structure: inner bevel/smooth/225%/up/4px/0px shading: 120rad/no global light/65rad/custom/screen white 75%/multiply black 75%

Contour: default 50%

Inner Shadow: structure: normal white/75%/-65rad/no global light/6px/0%/2px

Satin: structure: multiply black/20%/19rad/14px/21px

Gradient Overlay: gradient: normal/100%/#c4c4c4-#ffffff/linear/align with layer/132rad

Drop Shadow: structure: multiply black/85%/120rad/no global light/6px/0%/2px
```

**How can I create a sharp and realistic bevel on text in Photoshop?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Here is my shot**

[image]

I have used Drop Shadow, Inner Shadow, Bevel and Emboss, Gradient Overlay and Satin

---

**Screenshots of used effects**

> **Drop Shadow :**
>
> - [ Blend_Mode:multiply,100%,#000000 ]
> - [ Angle:120, Global_Light:No ]
> - [ 4px:0%:1px ]
> - [ Contour:Defaults/CoveDeep ]
> - [Noise: 0% ]

[image]

> **Inner Shadow :**
>
> - [ Blend_Mode:overlay,100%,#ffffff ]
> - [ Angle:120, Global_Light:No ]
> - [ 6px:20%:4px ]
> - [ Contour:Defaults/Linear, Anti-aliased:no]
> - [Noise: 0% ]

[image]

> **Bevel and Emboss :**
>
> - [ Inner Bevel:ChiselHard,Depth:300%,Up, 1px,0px ]
> - [ Angle:120, Global_Light:No ]
> - [ Altitude:58 ]
> - [ Contour:Defaults/Linear; AntiAliased:Yes ]
> - [ Highlight:normal-10%-#ffffff ]
> - [ Shadow:multiply-100%-#000000 ]
> - [Opacity: 100% ]

[image]

> **Contour :**
>
> - [ Cone-Inverted ]
> - [ Range:90% ]

[image]

> **Satin :**
>
> - [ Blend_Mode:overlay, 90%, #ffffff ]
> - [ Angle:50, Global_Light:No ]
> - [ 4px,0px ]
> - [ Contour:Defaults/Linear; AntiAliased:No; Invert:No ]

[image]

> **Gradient Overlay :**
>
> - [ Blend_Mode:normal, 100% ]
> - [ #b5b5b5-#ffffff, Reverse:No ]
> - [ STyle:Linear, Align_with_layer:Yes ]
> - [ Angle:120; scale:100% ]

[image]

Comment: yes! that's much closer! can you please add details?

Comment: Sure, Just let me save screenshots. :)

Comment: I added screenshots of layer styles, hope this will help. :)

Comment: don't tell me you are using XP...

Comment: I am not telling :)

Comment: I'd upvote if you wrote out the instructions. Search engines can't pickup text in screenshots.

Comment: Imstructions Added

Answer (score 6):

Well, you're on the right track. The key is to use layer styles.

Here's my shot:

[image]

Settings:

1. Add Bevel & Emboss. Choose "Chisel Hard" under technique, play around with the settings and use the "Cove - Deep" preset under Contour.

[image]

[image]

2. Add a dark grey to bright white linear Gradient Overlay. Angle it and limit it so that it begins with the white in the top left corner and ends with the dark grey.

[image]

3. Add a rather harsh and strong but only slightly distant drop shadow.

[image]

The difference is in the details though and getting that perfect emboss/glow is the tricky part. You might try dragging it through After Effects and using glow or perhaps simply pushing the contrast with curves in Photoshop.

Oh, and don't forget the noise (Filter > Noise).

**EDIT: combining some of my settings with those of S.M. will yield even better results. Take a look especially at his/her "Satin" and "Inner Shadow" settings.**

Comment: I'd upvote if you wrote out the instructions. Search engines can't pickup text in screenshots.